# Response.Redirect not working after clientScript execution

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, response

I have called a JavaScript method on an asp.net page using Clientscript:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Registering", String.Format("getTest('{0}'{1}'{2}');", FileName, ",", taskStr), true);
```

In JavaScript, I have called a C# static webmethod which is also available in

```
public partial class pagetest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 [WebMethod]
 public static void test(){Response.Redirect("tst.aspx");}
}
```

when test method was triggered from JavaScript `response.redirect` catches an error. I have tried `HTTPCOntext.curent.response` and `Http.cuttent.handler.reponse`.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.

Registering a client script puts the script on the page so that it will execute when the page is rendered in the browser.

Redirecting causes ASP.NET to abandon the page currently being rendered (including any registered client scripts)-- it is never sent to the client.  Instead, IIS will send a redirect header to the browser.  You could theoretically include page content after the redirect header (you'd have to write some pretty strange code), but most browsers will ignore it.

If you want the client script to execute, you must add it to the page that is the target of the redirect.